# Exception: Warning: Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php on line 71

Tags: magento2, error, exception, magento2.4.5

I have created new module in Magento 2.4.5-p1, the functionality work in the local environment, but when I add the module in the staging environment, I am facing this error in system.log.

> CRITICAL: Exception: Warning:
> include(/var/www/html/app/code/Abc/PoNumber/view/adminhtml/templates/order\create\form\po_number.phtml):
> Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php on
> line 71 in
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:62

Any idea how to resolve this error, I have already tried setup:upgrade and di compile multiple times, but the error still exists.

Comment: Can you double check if the `/var/www/html/app/code/Abc/PoNumber/view/adminhtml/templates/order\create\form\po_number.phtml` file actually exist on the staging environment ? Also verify the permissions on your module files and directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can see that it is slash issue, You are missing the slash in you phtml file, please change from

```
/var/www/html/app/code/Abc/PoNumber/view/adminhtml/templates/order\create\form\po_number.phtml
```

to

```
/var/www/html/app/code/Abc/PoNumber/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/form/po_number.phtml
```

Comment: I completely missed that, thank you @Ronak !!! It saves my day